# How to translate between two tag taxonomies?

Tags: predictive-models

I have a set of digital audio assets which have been tagged by two separate parties, using two separate tag taxonomies - say Taxonomy A and Taxonomy B. I am looking into the feasibility of using these two datasets to predict what a new asset’s tags would be in Taxonomy B given its tags in Taxonomy A.

I’ve been doing a lot of googling but I’m not finding much material that relates to this process. The majority of what I can find is about language translation and not statistical analysis!

I imagine it’s possible that there is some technical terminology for this process/area of study that I’m unaware of. Any advice, either in what I should be searching for, or materials themselves on this specific topic would be very helpful.